# Server side framework for Dart

Tags: dart

Is there any server-side framework for Dart with support for things like templating, session management, etc., like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) or [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/) for Node?

Comment: Some of the frameworks in the accepted answer are no longer being maintained. See [HTTP server frameworks for Dart](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/web-server-frameworks-for-dart-197a073299eb)

Comment: Embedded Dart template engine and compiler. Compiles templates to Dart source code. Examples of layout, header, footer, navigation, breadcrumbs, html utils etc. https://github.com/mezoni/edart

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, there are several server-side web frameworks for Dart. See the list below:

- [Aqueduct](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct) - Dart HTTP server framework for building REST APIs. Includes PostgreSQL ORM and OAuth2 provider.
- [Start](https://github.com/lvivski/start) - Sinatra-inspired web framework to serve static files, handle dynamic requests, web sockets and create JSON responses.
- [Angel](https://github.com/angel-dart/angel) - A server-side framework designed for full-stack development, with an emphasis on code sharing, scalability, and a low learning curve.
- [Redstone](https://github.com/luizmineo/redstone.dart) - A metadata-driven microframework.
- [Stream](https://github.com/rikulo/stream) - Lightweight web server with request routing, filtering, template engine, WebSocket, MVC design pattern, and file-based static resources.
- [Express](https://github.com/dartist/express) - A simple, thin expressjs inspired layer around Dart's primitive HttpServer APIs.
- [Shelf](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf) - Shelf makes it easy to create and compose web servers and parts of web servers.
- [Jaguar](https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar) - A server-side framework built for speed, simplicity, and extensibility.
- [Force](https://github.com/ForceUniverse/dart-force) - A real-time web framework, embracing web sockets, making communication even better.
- [Vane](https://github.com/dartvoid/vane) - A framework with built-in server runtime environment and middleware system.

See also [this list](https://github.com/yissachar/awesome-dart#server-frameworks).

---

Furthermore, there are a few Dart packages you can use to create your own server-side web framework.

For templating, there are two mustache libraries on `pub`, [mustache](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache4dart) and [mustache4dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache4dart).

For URL routing, see the [route](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route) package.

There are packages for databases, [mysql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky), [postgresql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql), and [mongodb](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart) and [couchbase](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/couchclient).

For caching, see [memcached](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/memcached_client).

I haven't seen any session management packages, you'll probably have to roll your own and persist session data using a database.

Comment: Angel actually rolls a templating engine called Jael as well.

Comment: Aqueduct has been discontinued and will no longer receive any support as per the developers on their website

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant can we maintain the repo ? I mean community can maintain as open source

Comment: @AliYarKhan You can but it would have to be a Github fork, as their repo has been archived. Gonna be difficult at this point to get it back to the mainstream

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant yeah ... but it was good one to be honest

Comment: Do all of these massively scale like Asynchronous I/O Node.js?

Answer (score 9):

[Redstone.dart](https://github.com/luizmineo/redstone.dart) seems interesting and uses the [Shelf](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf) packages. I have found it pretty easy to prototype with. It also is currently being contributed to unlike a lot of these other frameworks.

Answer (score 5):

Two interesting options may be :

1. http://rikulo.org/projects/stream

   Features include:

   - Request Routing
   - Request Filtering
   - Template Technology
   - File-based static resources
   - MVC design pattern
2. https://github.com/lvivski/start

   Simplier and Sinatra inspired framework - similar to express.js

Answer (score 3):

You have also [forcemvc](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/forcemvc), it is a serverside dart implementation that uses the same annotations and use cases as spring mvc. So if you are familiar with spring mvc it should be easy to start with forcemvc.

It is created for all the java developers, that want to start working with dart. Look at the [example](https://github.com/jorishermans/dart-forcemvc-example) application to get you started.

Forcemvc is part of the dart force framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is Dart version of Express (at least some part of it, from which you can start):

https://github.com/dartist/express

Answer (score 1):

I found interesting

- [bulls_eye](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bulls_eye)

> Bulls Eye is an Dart-IO Extension to build up an WebServer (like node.js and Express)
>
> [Redstone.dart](http://redstone.dart) (was [bloodless](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bloodless))
>
> but have not yet used them myself

Answer (score 1):

There is also DartVoid's [Vane](https://github.com/DartVoid/Vane) which seems really interesting. DartVoid will be probably the first Dart PaaS (if GAE still takes some time to support Dart) and they are putting effort on Vane to give a solid experience.

Answer (score 0):

For a large example of redstone.dart, see https://github.com/DirectMyFile/services